# How to convert list of buttons to radio buttons based on row overflow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

[**PLAYGROUND**](http://jsbin.com/ketexozegi/1/edit?html,css,output)

Given a container, I'd like to display a list of buttons in a single row.

However, if there is not enough space in a row to contain all the buttons, I'd like to display radio buttons instead.

For example, this:

[image]

should become:

[image]

But, this:

[image]

should stay as is.

Is that possible to achieve this using CSS only?

If not, how would you do this using Javascript?

[**PLAYGROUND**](http://jsbin.com/ketexozegi/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible in CSS.

Not too difficult in JavaScript.

First, add this style to `.container`:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

**JavaScript**

```
var cont= document.querySelectorAll('.container');

for(var i = 0 ; i < cont.length ; i++) {
  if(cont[i].scrollWidth > cont[i].clientWidth) {
    var buttons= cont[i].querySelectorAll('button');
    for(var j = 0 ; j < buttons.length ; j++) {
      var div= document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML= 
       '<label>'+
         '<input type="radio" name="button'+i+'">'+buttons[j].innerHTML+
       '</label>';
      cont[i].insertBefore(div, buttons[j]);
      buttons[j].remove();
    }
  }
}
```

[**Updated JS Bin**](http://jsbin.com/cohakelera/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 2):

Jquery solution

```js
var num=$('.one button').length
var count=0;
for(var x=0;x < num;x++){
   count=count+parseInt($('.one button').eq(x).width()) + parseInt($('.one button').eq(x).css('padding-left')) + parseInt($('.one button').eq(x).css('padding-right'))
}
if(count > $('.one').width()){
    $('.one button').each(function(){
        var val=$(this).text();
        $(this).replaceWith('<input type="radio"  />'+val+'</br>')
    })
}
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.one{
   width:200px; 
}
.one button{
    display:inline-block;
}
.one radio{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container one">
    <button>Yes,</button>
    <button>it</button>
    <button>is</button>
    <button>possible</button>
    <button>to</button>
    <button>achieve</button>
    <button>this</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <button>What</button>
    <button>do</button>
    <button>you</button>
    <button>think?</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can change the width of `.one` to see the change

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var parentElm = $('.parent');
  var parentWidth = parentElm[0].offsetWidth;

  var buttons = parentElm[0].children;
  var buttonsWidth = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    buttonsWidth += buttons[i].offsetWidth;
  }
  var buildRadio = '';
  if (buttonsWidth > parentWidth){
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
      var value = buttons[i].innerText;
      buildRadio += '<input type="radio" name="something" value="' + value + '">' + value + '<br>';
    }
    parentElm.html(buildRadio);
  }

});
```

for something like this

```
<div class="parent">

  <button>Hello</button>
  <button>World</button>
  <button>Cool</button>
  <button>Stuff</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clone your div to a temporary div.
Then you can change the temp div to no-wrap, invisible.
Then you can compare the innerWidth and scrollWidth of the temp div to detect if the text overflow or not.

```
$('#div1').clone().attr('id','tempDiv').css('white-space','nowrap').css('overflow','auto').appendTo(document.body).css('visibility','hidden');

if ($('#tempDiv').innerWidth() != $('#tempDiv')[0].scrollWidth) {
  alert('OK');
}
```

http://jsbin.com/heridapeqa/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output